# How do I get a CSS Selector to Skip Over?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I get a CSS selector to skip over `<dd>` and apply to all the `<dt>` only? I am trying to only apply `border-bottom` to the first `<dt>.`

I tried: `dl > dt:not(:last-child)`, but that didn't work either.

CSS:

```
dt:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Dates of Operation</dt>
    <dd style="display: none;"></dd>
    <dt>Dates of Operation</dt>
    <dd style="display: none;"></dd>
    <dt>Dates of Operation</dt>
    <dd style="display: none;"></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: If the last child is the special one you can add style to all dt and then to the last child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type):

```
dl > dt:first-of-type {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}
```

See **[demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/K5C7K/2)**.

As always, make sure you check for target browser support before using it. If you have a large audience, the standard way of achieving what you want is using a regular class.

Answer (score 1):

Use :first-child selector

`dl > dt:first-child {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2SZ9f/

Answer (score 0):

you can use first-child

It works exacly the same as last child but it's the first child. should work fine. Here is a codepen :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eFkbq

Answer (score 0):

It would depends on which is the special element. If the first is the only one with border then you should use

```
dt:first-child{
        border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}
```

But if you want to have border on every child except the last one, then try this:

```
dt {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}

dt:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

This will override the border bottom style added to dt elements.

If you only have 2 elements then you can add `id`, `class` or `first-child`. If the last child is the special one then add the css for it and you may have many other `dt` elements.

Comment: This will apply border-bottom to all `dt` except the last one. OP stated `I am trying to only apply border-bottom to the first <dt>.`

Comment: @rzr You are right, but the reason I suggest this is because he is trying to hide the border of the last. Let me edit to add clarification.